# Navigation Drawer showing only black icons

Tags: android, navigation, icons

I want to change navigation drawer icons, i am trying below code in Menu.xml file. But it showing only black icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".Welcome"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_kirtan"
        android:icon="@drawable/point_red"
        android:title="XYZ"/>
</group>
```

Expected output -

[image]

Please help me...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add below line in Activity class...

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add color like this :

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_kirtan"
        android:icon="@drawable/point_red"
        android:title="XYZ"
        android:tint="@color/redColor"
/>
```

or you can also do

```
  mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

This disables all state based tinting.

Comment: @MagicduetoLogic glad to help you , hope you can up-vote this .